# Pointer Arithmetic Question (size of array) [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    int  arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; 
    int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr; 

    return 0; 
}
```

How does `int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;`  find the size of the array exactly? I've read the explanation from geeksforgeeks and still a bit confused. I thought if you dereferenced (&arr + 1) then it would give you a nonexistent value since you're skipping ahead 6 integers, which can be anything random in that memory address? And also, if you're able to dereference (&arr + 1) to an int type, then how are you able to subtract that value from `arr`?

Comment: This may be useful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523585/how-do-sizeofarr-sizeofarr0-work

Comment: This will 100% help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c

Comment: there's another question exactly about this but the site doesn't correctly search for &x + 1 etc. ;(

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988158/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727045/) for discussion of whether this is legal or not

Answer (score 1):

`*(&arr + 1) - arr` is a pretty complicated way to write `6`.

`&arr` is a pointer to an `int[6]`

`(&arr + 1)` is a pointer to an `int[6]` that starts after the one at `arr`, i.e., it's 6 `int`s higher in memory.

`*(&arr + 1)` is that imaginary array after `arr`.  There is no array there, but we're not going to use it, so it doesn't matter.

In `*(&arr + 1) - arr`, the two integer arrays are converted to `int *` pointers to their first elements before the difference operation is applied.  Since these arrays are 6 `int`s apart in memory, there are 6 `int`s between those two pointers, and the result is 6.

Comment: Initially, I was also thinking that but it should be defined behavior!

Comment: "There is no array there, but we're not going to use it, so it doesn't matter."  - the code is still technically undefined behaviour since the semantics of the `*` operator are only defined for the case where the pointer points to a valid object, making the behaviour undefined by omission. There is an open CWG issue about the subject